# Equal to a new ArrayObject

Tags: php

I have a variable that is assigned as a new `ArrayObject`

```
$var = new ArrayObject();
```

I want to check if this variable is of type `ArrayObject` and **is in a newly instantiated state** (same property values and structure). One way seems to be using non strict evaluation `==` instead of `===`

```
if ($var == new ArrayObject) { echo 'true'; }
```

Given the crazy gotchas of PHP I don't know if `==` is just checking if both are simply objects or what. I want a more strict way of checking.

`gettype` simple returns `Object` which is of no use.

**EDIT**: `is_a()` seems to detect the type correctly but how then can I check if $var is in a newly instantiated state?

```
if (is_a($var, 'ArrayObject')) { echo 'true'; }
```

Comment: Why are you using ArrayObject instead of Array?

Comment: `json_encode` later to output an empty dictionary instead of array

Comment: use is_object() function

Comment: and how can I check if $var is in a newly instantiated state?

Comment: try using `isset`

Comment: edited just for you guys.

Comment: Do you need to check if the `ArrayObject` stored in `$var` was not used yet or if it is in the same state it was right after its creation? The first option is probably not directly achievable but for the second one, this is why `==` exists and works with object operands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method [`serialize`](http://php.net/manual/de/arrayobject.serialize.php) of [`ArrayObject`](http://php.net/manual/de/class.arrayobject.php) to check:

**See the following code (http://ideone.com/Frx0EH):**

```
$arr1 = new ArrayObject([1,2,3]);
$arr2 = new ArrayObject();
$arr3 = 'HelloWorld';

var_dump(isInitArrayObject($arr1)); //false
var_dump(isInitArrayObject($arr2)); //true
var_dump(isInitArrayObject($arr3)); //false

function isInitArrayObject($arr1) {
    if (!($arr1 instanceof ArrayObject)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $arr_init = new ArrayObject();
        return ($arr1->serialize() === $arr_init->serialize());
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. 
A similar way to check two objects is converting the ArrayObject instances into a json object using json_encode, then string-wise compare them.

Comment: Try the following code: `$x = new ArrayObject(); echo(serialize($x)."\n"); $x[1] = 0; echo(serialize($x)."\n"); unset($x[1]); echo(serialize($x)."\n");`. After `unset($x)`, `isInitArrayObject($x)` returns `TRUE` but the same does a simple comparison: `$x == new ArrayObject()`; there is no need for serialization or `instanceof`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
$arr1 = new ArrayObject([1,2,3]);
$arr2 = new ArrayObject();
$arr3 = 'HelloWorld';

var_dump((array) $arr1 == (array) new ArrayObject());
var_dump((array) $arr2 == (array) new ArrayObject());
var_dump((array) $arr3 == (array) new ArrayObject());
```